# Windows Phone 7, can I pass a parameter to ScheduledTaskAgent for a live tiles update?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to pass a string from the main app to my live tiles agent assembly?  There is a user preference I need to pass to the service so the service knows what to query a web service for....

Comment: Why not just save it in IsolatedStorage?

Comment: Actually, I figured out I can just use Isolated Storage to set my string in the main app and then retrieve the value within the tiles project.

lol, just read your comment will, didn't see it there.  You are right, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate from an app to an agent via Isolated Storage.

However, beware of both the app and the agent running at the same time as they cannot both access the same instance of IsolatedStorageSettings at the same time and you should be sure to lock the use of files appropriately if using them instead.

The safest way to communicate in this way (if appropriate to the app) is to write the information the agent needs before it is started. This way you can be sure to avoid any conflicts of access.

Comment: It's a string that i'm saving to Iso storage now.  The main app never reads from it only sets it.  The live tiles app only reads from and never sets it.   I should be good right?

Comment: @Jarrette sounds good to me and what I have working and tested without issue.

Comment: Details on best practises to this are at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944(v=VS.92).aspx